# Getting status of each test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I've been trying to create a platform similar to CodeWars. The thing is that, after I test the code made by the user, I need to catch if the test succeed or failed so I can render the feedback. Instead of getting the status by console, how can I get the status of a test after it has been run?

Comment: It sounds like you want a custom [reporter](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can check the exit code of the `test` process. If it is equal to 0, then tests were all green, if it is not equal to 0, then tests failed.

Comment: Someone told me the same thing. But I didn't find good documentation and examples of the process object. Any advice?

const jest = require("jest");
jest.run("./check.spec.js")